# Convert string json inside a json to a object java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, gson

I have a string like this

```
"{
    "scanReference": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "document": {
        "status": "data",
        "data": {
            "firstName": "FULL NAME",
            "info": "{\"city\":\"CITY\",\"issueDate\":\"2019-01-01\"}"
        },
        "country": "USA"
    }
}"
```

I have created class (simple POJO) to convert this to java object and using GSON. I am using the below code to convert to java object.

```
(gson.fromJson(response, MyClass.class));
```

But I am receiving the below error when converting , it because "info" is a string not json.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

The code works as expected when I made "info" a json and tested it, but it is string here.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

PS: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Create info class within MyClass.

```
Public class MyClass.class{
private String scanReference;
..........
private Info info

//Setter getter
}
```